# Options to synch informix database to sql server?

Tags: sql-server, informix

I am trying to get data from an informix database into a Sql Server database. The data needs to be synched either real time or at most 5 minutes.  It is about 20 tables and 4 or 5 Gigs, the data for a few tables changes frequently.  What are the options?

Comment: You may want to look into SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services).

Comment: Thanks.  we are considering SSIS, biz talk server with sql adapter, or a custom process.  We are open to more suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informix has a Change Data Capture interface, you can implement it and sync to SQL server in near real time

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cdc.doc/cdc.htm